# How to connect to CA-signed MQTT-server using mqtt.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, mqtt

I have searched for a few hours now to try to find the answer to this.

I want to use nodejs (using the [mqtt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) package) to connect to a MQTT server. The server has a CA signed certificate. I'm not in control of the server, but it is used by several other clients. When I use the windows app MQTTBox I can connect fine using the following settings:

[image: MQTTBox Settings]

When I try to do this using nodejs (mqtt.js) however, I get errors related to the certificate it seems.

Here's a simplification of the code I'm trying to use to connect from nodejs:

```
import mqtt from 'mqtt';
import tls from 'tls';

const options = tls.connect({
  host: 'mqtt.<domain>',
  port: 9883,
  username: '<username>',
  password: '<password>',
});

const client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://mqtt.<domain>:9883', options);
client.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected!');
});
client.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log('Error:', error);
});
```

Which gives me:

```
> Error: unable to verify the first certificate
>     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
>     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
>     at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
>     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
>     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12)
> Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
>     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
>     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
>   code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
> }
```

Is there some other setting I should use to indicate that the server has a CA-signed certificate? I thought this would be quite simple as long as the server had the cert, perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

## Update

The listener should be named "connect", not "connecting". As hardillb pointed out in his comment above, the options object should not manually be passed through tls.connect(), it is done by mqtt.js (it was just something I tried and forgot to remove).

Those changes leaves us with:

```
import mqtt from 'mqtt';

const options = {
  host: 'mqtt.<domain>',
  port: 9883,
  username: '<username>',
  password: '<password>',
};

const client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://mqtt.<domain>:9883', options);
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected!');
});
client.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log('Error:', error);
});
```

Which also, repeatedly, gives the following error:

```
> Error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
>     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
>     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
>     at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
>     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
>     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12) {
>   code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
> }
> Error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
>     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
>     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
>     at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
>     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
>     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12) {
>   code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
> }
...
```

If I add `rejectUnauthorized: false` to the options, it works as intended. I'm quite sure the server CA is letsencrypt, is that not considered safe by node?

I'm sitting on a windows 10 machine originally with nodejs v12.16.1, updated now to v12.18.0, which gave the same result.

Comment: Which CA signed the brokers certificate? Also what version of NodeJS are you using

Comment: Also why are you calling `tls.connect({...})` and using the returned `TLSSocket` as the options passed to the `mqtt.connect()`?

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure the CA for the domain is letsencrypt. The tls.connect is wrong though! It was something I just tried that lived on :/. Combined with that my listener should be for "connect" and not "connecting" I'm actually getting the connection to open, so the other problem I had must have been in my larger code base. Thank you! :)

Comment: Actually, it didn't work. I had added the "rejectUnauthorized: false" as well, which made it work. I would like it to work without it though. As I wrote I'm quite sure letsencrypt is used, is that not ok for node? Updated the question.

Comment: Back to the other half of the original question, what version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: @hardillb Sorry, I'm using nodejs v12.18.0, had v12.16.1 before but just updated.